EF Core - disconnected deleted child not deleted
Using EF Core 8, trying to delete a child element of an 1:n relationship fails when in a new DB context.
Within one DB context it is no problem to delete one child from an 1:n relation, after SaveChanges() the child is also deleted in the database.
For example:
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = db.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BlogId == blogId);

    if (blog != null)
    {
        blog.Url += $"/changed";
        if (blog.Posts.Count > 0)
        {
            // this one gets deleted - okay, we are in the same db context
            blog.Posts.Remove(blog.Posts[0]);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

But in a disconnected scenario that doesn't work.
Here I read the data using one DB context, change the values and try to store the changed values in a second DB context.
In the real project the data is read by a Web-GUI, and later the changed data is transferred via JSON, so there is no way to keep a DB context open.
Blog? existingBlog = new();

using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    existingBlog = db.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BlogId == blogId);
}

// change values, add Posts and delete Posts
Blog updatedBlog = ChangeValuesOfBlogAndPosts(existingBlog!);

// here we are in a new db context
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    db.Blogs.Update(updatedBlog);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

Now all changes made in the 1-Side (here: Blogs) are saved, all changes in the n-Side ( = Posts) are saved, all new Posts to a Blog are saved, but deleted Posts are still in the DB, so at the next read we still have all deleted data.
I've read many posts, tried several syntactical variations, I found a hint to a "Detached Mapper", but I think this is a quite basic feature and it is working when I am just in one DB context, so I fear I am just missing one little thing to get it running without tools.
In case it is of any importance, the database behind is Oracle 19.
So thank you for any help.

What is your delete configuration between parent and child entities?

What do you mean by "delete configuration"?
My code is based on the Oracle standard example with Blogs and Posts, Blog has a List Posts { get; set; }, Post has a int BlogId { get; set; } and a Blog Blog { get; set; }

and as I mentioned, inside the same DB context everything works as expected.


EF Core do not detect any changes from detached entities. What you heve to do is to repeat deletes, updates, inserts of collections on attached entity, just retrieved from second active context. I have made function which helps in such sitution MergeCollections. Anyway pulling EF Core model to the world is bad practice, you have to use DTO classes.

@Martin I mean this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/timesten/22.1/cache/delete-cascade-cache-table-attribute.html

@SvyatoslavDanyliv:
Thank you for your comment, but as I stated, updates (on both sides of the 1:n relationship) and inserts (on the n-side) just work fine. The only thing NOT working is the detection of deletes on the n-side. (and for the model / DTO classes: thank you for the hint, but this is just minimal test code to investigate the problem)

@Jivopis: Delete Cascade reacts on a deletion of the parent, but the parent is not deleted, only one of the children, which in turn is not reflected in the DB.

> The only thing NOT working... - not working updates of navigation collections, not working deletes, so for you inserts is everything?

Your code example and description don't make sense. Your code example is one piece of code all together run at the same time. Your description says that there is JSON that is transferred later. Where is this JSON? I do not see it in your code. In general, this just looks like you should have an endpoint that takes in json and update the database based on the received data - a simple update (a PUT or PATCH endpoint - done the "normal" way, not with detached entities).

What it all boils down to is that db.Blogs.Update(updatedBlog) doesn't inform EF that any posts were deleted because the context never saw them. You probably have to run ChangeValuesOfBlogAndPosts while keeping the first context alive and then save changes. But we can't see what happens in ChangeValuesOfBlogAndPosts.

@topsail, I mentioned JSON only to show the reason why I have a different DB context.
I tracked down the problem to the new DBContext, using one DBContext everything is fine, but I have to use two of them, which causes the problem.

@GertArnold, ChangeValuesOfBlogAndPosts() is just a replacement for the changes happening in the GUI in the real application. As stated in the post, data is given to the GUI, the user changes values, adds and deletes elements, ant then I get the result back in a JSON. I had hoped EF can find these changes, but I am just learning, that this is not the case.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv, EF recognizes updates of existing elements, inserts of elements, but no deletes. As long as I don't delete anything everything works as expected, changed data is updated, new data is added. But when I delete an element it remains in the database and will be fetched next time the datastructure is read.

You cannot update detached object graphs quite that simply, and you will also run into issues when it comes to association references. (new/updated entity changing associations referencing other existing entity rows vs. collections/instances belonging under that entity.)
As you've noted you cannot keep the same DbContext instance open between requests. Within a single request EF's change tracking would monitor the collections so that when you remove an item EF knows to delete it. When you detach and serialize that entity and it's collection, modify it, then pass it back to another DbContext then there is no change tracking.
Update will essentially Attach an entity to the DbContext to start tracking changes from that point in time. The documentation for EF covers this quite well: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) Scroll down to "Handling Deletes" and "Mix of New and Existing Entities".
Essentially when updating an entity, fetch the entity from the DB including the associations, then determine which entities need to be inserted vs. removed vs. updated. It's a bit more work and since you cannot really count on the entity graph you can consider streamlining down the data payload serialized to JSON and back to use lightweight DTO rather than serializing entities. The additional benefit beyond packet sizes over the wire is that this helps guard from over-exposing the internal data structure of your service.

thank you for pointing me to this part of the documentation, I've read a lot but overlooked that one. Until now I was very enthusiastic how easy EF is to use, but I see, I have to add "a bit" more code (naturally, my code consists of some more classes than just blogs and posts...)
